# Sphinx / Manticore - base one plain index off another?

Tags: sphinx, manticore-search

I have a plain text index that sucks data from MySQL and inserts it into Manticore in a format I need (e.g. converting datetime strings to timestamp, CONCATing some fields etc.

I then want to create a second plain text index based off this data to group it further. This will save me having to either re-run the normalisation that's done to the first index on `INSERT` or make it easier for me to query in the future.

For example, my first index is a list of all phone calls that have been made / received (telephone number, duration, agent). The second index should group by Year-Month-Date in such a way that I can see how many calls each agent made on that day. This means I end up with `idx_phone_calls` and `idx_phone_calls_by_date`.

Currently, I generate the first index from MySQL, then get Manticore to query itself (by setting the MySQL host to localhost. It works, but it feels as though I should be able to query Manticore directly from within the index. However, I'm struggling to find if that's possible.

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Sphinx/Manticore, has its own GROUP BY function. So maybe can just run the final query against the original index anyway, avoid the need for the second index.
Sphinx's Aggregation (in some way) is more powerful than MySQL, and can do some 'super aggregation' functions (like with `WITHIN GROUP ORDER BY`)

But otherwise there is no direct way to create an off another (eg there is no `CREATE TABLE idx_phone_calls_by_date SELECT ... FROM  idx_phone_calls ...` )

Your 'solution' of directing `indexer` to query the data from `searchd` is good. In general this should be pretty efficent, particully on localhost, there is little overhead. Maintains the logical seperation of searchd being for queries, indexer being for well building indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've ended up essentially running a second call to MySQL to get the data instead, as whilst the localhost approach seemed to work, I found that it didn't always generate the table in the Manticore index (i.e. it didn't show in `SHOW TABLES` but did show on disk. Running the second MySQL query seems fine, especially as I can run it at a different time period to avoid unnecessary load on the database.

Comment: that sounds like didnt have `--rotate` when built the second index, so indexer built it, bu never told searchd to load it.

Comment: I think I hadn't restarted the `manticore` service using `systemd`. Once I did that, the index was there.

Comment: Shouldnt need to explicitly 'restart' searchd (the binary running the query engine!) to load the new index. Using --rotate switch on indexer is **better** as it just 'reloads' searchd, which means it loads n the new index without a full restart. The reload is 'seamless' in that shouldnt affect running queries (ie having a period of downtime)